# Laravel Simplexml error not yet possible to assign complex types to properties

Tags: json, xml, laravel, simplexml

Receiving an error **It is not yet possible to assign complex types to properties** when trying to put a new array into an object.

```
    $file = '/path/file.xml';

    $terms = array(
        'Title' => [
            'name' => 'name'
        ]
    );

    $term =  json_decode( json_encode($terms), true);

    $data = simplexml_load_file($file);
    list($result) = $data->xpath('(//Key1/Key2)');
    $number = count($result);
    $data->Key1[$number] = $term;
    $data->asXML($file);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please post the exact error message you got? Thank you!

Comment: what is `->Key1[$number]` here, what do you want by writing an object property like that